# $\frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^x}{x!}$ is Log-concave in $\lambda$?

Tags: convex-analysis

Poisson distribution of random variable $X$ with parameter $\lambda$ is defined as $p(x;\lambda)=\frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^x}{x!}$.

**Question:** How to show analytically that $p(\lambda)$ is not concave but log-concave in parameter $\lambda$ for a fixed value of $x$?

$p(\lambda)$ looks like quasi-concave shown below:

[image]

$\operatorname{Log}p(\lambda)$ looks like log-concave shown below:

[image]

**My Work:** The sign of the second derivative would determine the concavity/convexity of $p(x)$ in $\lambda$ but its second derivative is not that easy to examine:

$p''(\lambda)= \frac{e^{-\lambda} (x-1) x \lambda^{x-2}-2 e^{-\lambda} x \lambda^{x-1}+e^{-\lambda} \lambda^x}{x!}$.

Whereas second derivative of $\operatorname{Log}(p(\lambda))$ is:

$\operatorname{Log}(p(\lambda))^{''}=-e^{\lambda } x x! \lambda ^{-x-1} \left(\frac{e^{-\lambda } x \lambda ^{x-1}}{x!}-\frac{e^{-\lambda } \lambda ^x}{x!}\right)+e^{\lambda } x! \lambda ^{-x} \left(\frac{e^{-\lambda } (x-1) x \lambda ^{x-2}}{x!}-\frac{2 e^{-\lambda } x \lambda ^{x-1}}{x!}+\frac{e^{-\lambda } \lambda ^x}{x!}\right)+e^{\lambda } x! \lambda ^{-x} \left(\frac{e^{-\lambda } x \lambda ^{x-1}}{x!}-\frac{e^{-\lambda } \lambda ^x}{x!}\right).$

Comment: Wait... $\log p(\lambda)=-\lambda+x\log\lambda-\log x!$ and you pretend that the second derivative of $\log p(\lambda)$ is... this?

Comment: I agree with Did here. Perhaps your confusion is a result of not simplifying $\log(p(\lambda))$ before differentiating? Yet this simplification is a standard trick in calculus; it is exactly the point of "logarithmic differentiation".

Comment: Got it. $\operatorname{Log}(p(\lambda))^{''}=-\frac{x}{\lambda^2}$. Thanks.